# Avoid leading numbers in xml element name

Tags: java, regex, xml

I would like to have a Java method for replacing leading numbers in the xml element name. For example,`<1396-tt5m>25K</1396-tt5m>` needs to be transformed to `<a-tt5m>25K</a-tt5m>`. Please take a look to my method for this:

```
public static String removeLeadNumbersFromXMLTagElements(String xml) throws TransformerException {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<[^>]*?[^[0-9]][^>]*?>)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        while (m.find()) {
            String replace = m.group().replaceAll("[^[0-9]]+", "a");            
            m.appendReplacement(result, replace);
        }

        m.appendTail(result);
        return result.toString();
    }
```

But the result of my method is:`<a-ttam>25K</a-ttam>`. Could you please help with correct regex? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
public static String removeLeadNumbersFromXMLTagElements(String xml) throws TransformerException {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\<.*?)[0-9]+(.*?\\>)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        String replace = m.group(1) + "a" + m.group(2);
        m.appendReplacement(result, replace);
    }

    m.appendTail(result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: This solution is very similar to mine, thank you! Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

So this is not exactly what you wanted, but it should solve the problem. It will get the tag and then remove any leading digits, but nothing else. This code replaces your while loop. Your code is fine for identifying tags, but (as you noted) it is replacing all digits, not just the leading ones.

```
while (m.find()) {
//System.out.println(m.group());
String work = m.group();
String replace = m.group();
if (work.substring(0, 2).equals("</")) {
    //System.out.println("end tag");
    if (work.length() > 2 && Character.isDigit(work.charAt(2))) {
        replace = "</a";
        int i = 3;
        while (i < work.length() && Character.isDigit(work.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        replace += work.substring(i);
    }
} else if (work.substring(0, 1).equals("<")) {
    //System.out.println("begin tag");
    if (work.length() > 1 && Character.isDigit(work.charAt(1))) {
        replace = "<a";
        int i = 2;
        while (i < work.length() && Character.isDigit(work.charAt(i))) {
            i++;
        }
        replace += work.substring(i);
    }
}
m.appendReplacement(result, replace);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice solution! Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Mine solution: I finally found that `I can use String replace = m.group().replaceFirst("[^[0-9]]+", "a")` instead of `replaceAll`. That also works!